# Android: using resources from another project in my workspace

Tags: java, android, xml, resources, multiple-projects

I am fairly new to Android development - coming from a WPF background.

I have created two Android projects in my "workspace" in Eclipse.  One is called "TestProject", and the other called "TestLibraryProject".

Inside of "TestLibraryProject" I have created a custom view called BlueBox.

I now want to use BlueBox in my main layout of "TestProject".  Knowing that I needed to reference "TestLibraryProject" from "TestProject" somehow, I right-clicked on "TestProject" and followed the menu:

Build Path -> Add Libraries

In the dialog that popped up I selected "Android Classpath Container", and in the immediate dialog following that I chose "TestLibraryProject" from the combo-box.

Two-fold question:
1.  Is this the correct way to include "TestLibraryProject" into "TestProject" so that I can use it?
2.  How can I now use BlueBox in my main layout XML?

I tried simply putting this in into the XML file:

```
<mypackage.TestLibraryProject.BlueBox
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

But that didn't work.  I also tried referencing the namespace in my root layout element:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:binding="http://www.gueei.com/android-binding/"
    xmlns:testlibrary="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android/mypackage2.TestLibraryProject"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

But that didn't seem to help.

Any suggestions?  Ideas?  Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Hope this will help you http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add a library project first make sure that your library project is actually marked as a `library project`.

> Right click on the project node --> properties --> Android --> *Is Library* checkbox --> OK

Then in your main Android project:

> Right click the project node --> properties --> Android --> Add -->
>   Select your library project --> OK --> OK

Comment: Thanks Damian, that's been bugging me for the last couple of hours